# Change background element's background-color and text color when clicked on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a header and a footer that work perfectly when the user is on a desktop and has a mouse and can hover over them and navigate everything that way.

The problem is on mobile when there is no mouse, I need everything to work as close to the same as it does on desktop. I was almost able to make the "PROJECTS" drop-down work to my liking when clicked as well as the "CONNECT" drop-up, but I'm having two issues.

The first problem I'm having is when "PROJECTS" or "CONNECT" drop-ups/drop-downs are clicked, when I click off them or I click them again, the drop-up/drop-down doesn't vanish. It becomes constantly displayed block and I need it to go back to display: none when the user clicks anywhere else or clicks "PROJECTS"/"CONNECT" a second time. I thought the "else" statement in the script I'm using would accomplish that, but apparently it is not working and I'm not sure why! What is the best way to make that work?

The second problem I'm having is when the user clicks on the li item "ONE" inside "PROJECTS" or any of the li items inside "CONNECT", I need the background of the clicked element to turn black and the text to turn white right before it loads the link (similar to how it looks on the desktop version using the :hover css). At this point, when they are clicked it just flashes the gray highlight color over the element for a split second. I tried adding the same type of css but changing "hover" to "focus" or "visited" and I couldn't get either to work. What is the best way to accomplish that?

Here is a JSFiddle of all the code: http://jsfiddle.net/xmdzg8vu/

If you view the JSFiddle on desktop, it will be hard to see the issues I'm having since you have a mouse and can hover... hopefully having the code will help with finding my errors though!

HTML:

```
<div id="background"></div>
<header id="header">
  <div id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li id="projects" onclick="displayDropdown()">
        PROJECTS
        <ul>
          <a href="/one" class="blocklink" target="_self">
            <li id="one">ONE</li>
          </a>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
<footer id="footer">
  <div id="footer-nav">
    <ul>
      <li id="connect" onclick="displayDropup()">
        CONNECT
        <ul>
          <a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank" class="blocklink">
            <li id="instagram">
              INSTAGRAM
            </li>
          </a>
          <a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank" class="blocklink">
            <li id="twitter">
              TWITTER
            </li>
          </a>
          <a href="mailto:mail@mail.com" class="blocklink">
            <li id="email">
              EMAIL
            </li>
          </a>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</footer>
```

JS and CSS are seen in the JSFiddle.

Thank you so much!

UPDATE: I have updated my JSFiddle to remove extra script not applicable to this question. Hopefully that cleans it up a little!

Comment: `:focus` would be the correct keyword in your css. (not `:focused`)

Comment: I will make that change now, thank you!

Comment: It’s my pleasure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second problem, have you tried the ***:active*** selector? For example, using part of your CSS code:

```
#one:focused, #one:visited, #one:hover, #one:active {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried that, I will try it right now. Thank you!

Comment: :active selector didn't work unfortunately. Thank you for the suggestion! :)

Comment: Check the next link:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_active2
It work on my mobile phone when the items with :active selector are clicked. Also, your JSFiddle example works too when the Instagram link is clicked, it turns black with the text white before jumping to instagram.

Comment: Hmm maybe I somehow made a mistake, I'll give it another go! Thank you and my apologies!

Comment: Ayyyye! It worked perfectly for Instagram, Twitter, and Email. For some reason it didn't work for "ONE". Any ideas? Thank you!!!

Comment: No, but you can try to make changes progressively to the "ONE" link untils it have similar attributes and equal CSS style compared to the other elements. In this process you should find the element that is messing up things.

Comment: I will give that a go, thank you heaps for your help sir.

Comment: After making CSS changes one at a time, none seemed to do the trick. The CSS for all the li items are equivalent, I've got no idea what is causing "ONE" to not work. If anyone does find the issue, let me know! :)

Comment: Try changing html attributes for the "ONE" link also, for example:
href="https://www.google.com"
target="_blank"

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are some issues in your markup. Normally we don't nest `ul>a`. We normally do `ul>li>a`.

For problem #1 you could add an `onclick` event handler to the submenu li to close the dropdown (/dropup) ul when a submenu item is clicked.

Let me know if that works. You might also want to use touch events for mobile (even thought `click` might work).

Comment: Thank you for the response! I love the idea of adding an "onclick event handler to the submenu li to close the dropdown (/dropup) ul when a submenu item is clicked." I'll try that now. Do you happen to also know the best way to close the dropdown/dropup if the user clicks on "PROJECTS" or "CONNECT" a second time and the best way to close the dropdown/dropup when the user clicks anywhere off the submenu (they don't end up clicking any of the li items and just want the dropup/dropdown to close). Once I get both of those covered, I think they will be good for what I need it to do! Thank you!!

Comment: Do you think this would work syntax wise for your suggestion? Adding onclick="hideDropdown()"                                                                                    to the "ONE" li item in "PROJECTS" and then including this script:             
    function hideDropdown() {
    var x = document.getElementById("nav ul ul");
    if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
    } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
    }
    }

Comment: I am a little unsure that a space separated id will work. Can you please change your code to use `document.querySelector`.

Comment: The space separated id has been working for the two functions already in the JSFiddle, so I thinkkk they should work for this too, fingers crossed. Could you help me understand the difference between document.getElementById and document.querySelector ? Haven't ran across this thus far. Thank you!!!

Comment: Actually hmm I don't think I want the submenu to close when an li item is clicked because then it wouldn't show the background turning black and the text turning white... correct?

Comment: I think the submenu should close. querySelector uses a CSS style to selecting dom elements. Therefore, if you wanted to pick the div with email then you would say document.querySelector('#email")  and get it. With document.getElementById you would just say "email" in the argument.

Comment: Hi, @JohnSmith can you please repost the updated fiddle link in your the question ?  Let me see if I can get this working.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't sure what ID should be used for the querySelector, so I stuck with getElementById for now... Here is the updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/un8qd7ha/